Optimizing Plot Matching Using Python
I want to match Project Plots (PP) to Control Plots (CP); for each project plot, I have to match K CPs; if a control plot has already been chosen for a project plot, it can't be selected again (no replacement). To do the match, I have a CSV file containing the multivariate distance between each PP and each CP;
Something like:

but I have 30 PP and ~200000 CP.
I want to ensure that the overall distances between PP and CP are the minimum when doing the match.
Some time a ago,based on this question I asked here, I implemented the script below. The problem is that the result of the match depends on what PP we start with. I would like to find a way that considers the best possibility among all. Is there an algorithm that I can use for it?
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('PP_CP_dist.csv')

cols = [c for c in df.columns if c.startswith("dist")]

project_data = []
assignments = []
k = 2

for c in cols:
    for i in range(1, k+1):
        row = {}
        print(assignments)
        search_df = df.loc[~df.control_plot_id.isin(assignments)]
        control_plot = search_df.loc[search_df[c].idxmin()]
        row["project_plot"] = c
        row["control_plot"] = control_plot.control_plot_id
        row["dist"] = control_plot[c]
        project_data.append(row)
        assignments.append(control_plot.control_plot_id)

out_data = pd.DataFrame(project_data)

out_data.to_csv('PP_CP_dist_matched.csv')



Welcome to [so]. I think your question is too broad. Questions that ask for general guidance regarding a problem approach are typically are not a good fit for this site.  Split your task into smaller ones and start working on them. And ask particular questions related to particular issues you encounter. Here's how: how-to-ask
